# When I apply scd type2 my data comes as a new line and the data is multiplexed

Tags: ssis

I created my ssis package. After doing etl operations, I printed my package to the target database. then I created another package within the same organization and installed scd type 2. Every time the package is run, all the information in the source comes back as a new row. And the data is multiplying. Can you help me?

Am I making a mistake preparing the scd setup or is there something wrong with my packages and printing to the destination?